# Maths olympiad Geometry problem

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

Perhaps the title isn’t specific enough, but I have no better way to describe it.

> As shown below, diagonals of convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ intersect at $O$. Construct $F$ and $E$ on $AC$ so that $\angle BAC=\angle ADE,\angle BCA=\angle CDF$. If $\dfrac{OE}{OF}=\dfrac{OC}{OA}$, show that $AB=BC$.

[image]

Here, I find that the definition of the points gives me no idea how to solve the problem.

Edit: below are my thoughts. Denote $x=\angle BAC,y=\angle BCA,\alpha=\angle ADC$.

From [here](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%88%86%E8%A7%92%E5%AE%9A%E7%90%86/10805648?fr=aladdin) we get $$\frac{AF}{FC}=\dfrac{AD}{DC}\cdot\frac{\sin(\alpha-y)}{\sin y},\frac{AE}{EC}=\frac{AD}{DC}\cdot\frac{\sin x}{\sin(\alpha-x)}.$$

Note that $AB=BC\Longleftrightarrow x=y$. Moreover, multiply the two equations to get $$\Longleftrightarrow\frac{AF\cdot AE}{FC\cdot EC}=\frac{AD^2}{DC^2}.$$

Comment: Should it be $\angle BAC=\angle ADE$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition $\dfrac{OE}{OF}=\dfrac{OC}{OA}$ is equivalent to $OE \cdot OA = OC \cdot OF$. This means that $O$ has equal powers with respect to the circumcircles of $AED$ and $CFD$. Both circles pass through $D$, so $OD$ is the radical axis of these circles. Can you finish the solution now?

Comment: I’ve finished it now based on your hint. This method is great!